# WPF How to cast Listbox SelectedItem to type using XAML only

Tags: wpf, xaml, casting, listbox, selecteditem

Don't know how to word this better than an example. Consider I have two classes.

```
public class Person {
    public Hair Hair { get; set; }
}
public class Hair {
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a listbox (MyListBox) whose ItemSource is a list of Person.

Now I have a textblock which needs to display the selected list item. I want to be able to cast the SelectedItem to a Person, so that the textbox can display the Hair Color.

I can set datacontext to the Hair property like this (and this works):

```
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=SelectedItem.(local:Person.Hair)}"
Text="{Binding Color}"
```

But what I'd really like is to cast as a Person to the DataContext, something like below (which doesn't work):

```
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=SelectedItem.(local:Person)}"
Text="{Binding Hair.Color}"
```

How do I cast the SelectedItem as just a Person in XAML?

Comment: No need to set the `DataContext` explicitly, you can use `Text="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=SelectedItem.Hair.Color}"` instead.

Comment: Yes that works although that creates a warning in the editor which I'd like to avoid. As the first example worked by casting to Person.Hair, I thought there must be a way just to cast to Person?

Comment: How about simply: `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=SelectedItem}` and then `Text="{Binding Hair.Color}"`?